# AutoHotKey Ctrl in Caps Lock doesn't work with shift

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I don't have big fingers nor can I hit the ctrl key with my palm. Since I use ctrl for so many hotkeys, I had to remap it to the capslock button. I lived with it fine using the registry method for swapping ctrl and caps, but now I need to share this keyboard for pair programming. The main problem I'm having is that I can't use the ctrl-shift- shortcuts with the Capslock button anymore. Here's my autohotkey script.

```
+Space::Send _
#InstallKeybdHook
Capslock::
Send {LControl Down}
KeyWait, CapsLock
Send {LControl Up}
if ( A_PriorKey = "CapsLock" )
{
 if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
 {
   SetCapsLockState, off
 }
 else if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "F") = 0
 {
   SetCapsLockState, on
 }
}
return
```

Notice that I also have a line for shift space to send an underscore. I don't know how to set this up to cover all the possible holes. 
I appreciate any input in optimizing this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to +Dymn at #ahk for helping me out with this and working out all the bugs with me. Some of the defects we've encountered are Ctrl+Shift+ only works when Ctrl is the first one pressed, Capslock kept toggling CAPS when it wasn't the first key pressed even though another key was pressed before or after, and others. I've tested this and it appears to be a lot more robust with no apparent bugs.

```
#InstallKeybdHook
+Space::Send _
CapsLock::
#UseHook On
Send {LControl Down}
KeyWait,CapsLock
Send {LControl Up}
KeyWait, CapsLock
IF (A_PriorKey = "CapsLock") {
  IF GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1 {
    SetCapsLockState, OFF
  }
  Else If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "F") = 0 {
    SetCapsLockState, ON
  }
}
Return
+CapsLock::
Send {LControl Down}
KeyWait,CapsLock
Send {LControl Up}
Return
#UseHook OFF
```

This script is invaluable for me. I just hope someone else would find it as useful as I did.